# How can I update a PrimeFaces chart without having to refresh the entire page?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I've got a web page with a form in it, which includes a linked image, which whenever clicked, it will request the `graphicBean`, as well as the execution of the action `graficarTorta` (`action` of the `CommandLink`) and once the function has been generated, it must update the label with the `id`: `graficaGenerada` (`update` of the `CommandLink`).

At the end of the page you can find the `PanelGroup` label which contains the `graficaGenerada` `id`, that is to say, whenever the whole `graficarTorta` function has executed, the `update` label is the one from `PanelGroup`, which title is `Gráfica resultante`.

In the bean, the variables `model` and `example` are `new PieChartModel()` and `"ONE"` respectively. When the function is executed, the variable `model` turns into a graph of specific data and `example` turns into `"TWO"`.

Problem is that visually  turns into a `"TWO"`, but  doesn't show anything. I'm sure the only problem has to do with renderization or some visual component, because once I refresh the page, the chart is displayed with the updated data.

How can I make the chart show the updates without refreshing the whole page?

This is my code:

graficas.xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGroup id="pG_descripcionFormulario">
        <p:commandLink update = ":graficaGenerada" process="@this" action="#{graphicBean.graficarTorta}">
            <b:image value = "../resources/imgs/torta.jpg" style = "width:200px;height: 200px" class = "img-circle efectoZoom"/>
            <f:ajax execute="pG_descripcionFormulario" render="pG_descripcionFormulario" />
        </p:commandLink>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
...
<h:panelGroup id = "graficaGenerada">
    <h1>Gráfica resultante</h1>
    <h:outputText value = "#{graphicBean.example}"/>
    <p:chart type = "pie" model="#{graphicBean.model}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

GraphicBean.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import model.entities.Formulario;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.PieChartModel;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class GraphicBean {

    private PieChartModel model;
    private String example = "ONE";

    public GraphicBean() {
        model = new PieChartModel();
    }


    public String graficarTorta() {
        example = "DOS";
        model = new PieChartModel();
        model.set("A",1);
        model.set("B",2);
        model.set("C",3);
        model.setTitle("Gráfica de torta");
        model.setLegendPosition("w");
        return "grafica";
    }

    public PieChartModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(PieChartModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getExample() {
        return example;
    }

    public void setExample(String example) {
        this.example = example;
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What is the purpose of the f:ajax? Try for a test to delete it.